# Start a jboss service with ansible

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible, continuous-deployment

I wrote a simple ansible playbook to stop and start a jboss service, problem is on the server when I start the service manually it requires a password, but when I run the playbook it throws and error even though the password is provided.

Here is the playbook.

[image: playbook]

and this is the error I get when I ran it

```
PLAY [dev] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [10.33.122.122]

TASK [Stop jboss server] *******************************************************
fatal: [10.33.122.122]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "standard in must be a tty\n"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'main.retry'.         [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.33.122.122              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: And you can stop `jboss` service with `jbosssvc` user from CLI?

Comment: Yes but it requires a password and i input it as required then it stops, how do I do the same on a playbook though?

Comment: So the answer is not “yes”, but “no”.

Comment: The answer is yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > And you can stop `jboss` service with `jbosssvc` user from CLI?
>
> Yes but it requires a password and i input it as required then it stops, how do I do the same on a playbook though?

It means `jbosssvc` is not allowed to stop the service (which is somewhat expected situation), thus you cannot use `become_user: jbosssvc` directive.

You must become `root` to perform this operation (and this requires connecting user to be able to run commands with elevated permissions).

Comment: Thanks, it works with my account. but I did not want to use my account to achieve this, will probably create an new user with privileges that I need. Thanks again